# Sequence spaces on $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{\Gamma}$

Tags: functional-analysis

It's easy to prove that basic properties in $l_p(\mathbb{N})$ and $l_p(\mathbb{\Gamma})$, with $1\leq p\leq\infty$ and $\Gamma$ an index set (with arbitrary cardinal), are the same.

But, these sequences spaces can be compared, i.e, it can be proved that there are continuos injections or bijections between them?

Comment: What are these "basic" properties? If $p<\infty$ then $\ell_p(\mathbb N)$ is separable while $\ell_p(\Gamma)$ is not.

Comment: If $\Gamma \subseteq \Gamma'$ then there is an obvious isometry from $\ell_p(\Gamma)$ into $\ell_p(\Gamma')$ by setting the extra coordinates we might have to $0$...